# why am I getting a ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (4,)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I'm trying to find all red pixels in a png file and output a binary image file, and I feel like I'm close. I have to use double for loops as it's a requirement for my assignment.

this is is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as mat_plot

def find_red_pixels(map_filename, upper_threshold=100, lower_threshold=50):
    """find the red pixels and output as binary and save into jpeg file """
    rgb = mat_plot.imread(map_filename)
    rgb = rgb*255
    rgb = np.array(rgb)
    r = rgb[:,:,0]
    g = rgb[:,:,1]
    b = rgb[:,:,2]
    for i in range(0, 255): # iterate through each pixel
        for j in range(0, 255):
            colour = rgb[i,j]
            """if pixel meets these conditions then it is red"""
            if(colour[0]>upper_threshold):
                if(colour[1]<lower_threshold):
                    if(colour[2]<lower_threshold):
                        rgb[i,j] = [0,0,0]
    mat_plot.imsave('map-red-pixels.jpg', rgb.astype(np.uint8)) # save into jpeg
```

However, i get this error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (4,)
```

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. debug and research your issue. learn the libraries. google errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your input image is RGBA (e.g. a PNG with an alpha channel), your `rgb[i,j]` is actually *four* values, not three.

I also don't understand why you're looping over `range(0, 255)`. If the input image isn't 256x256, your program will crash. Why not loop based on the actual size of `rgb` instead?